# How to upload image to firebase using react native

Tags: react-native

I need way to upload image to firebase

i tried to use react-native-fetch-blob library

but I think there is something wrong with installing the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `react-native-fetch-blob`. Here is how I do it on my project.

1. Install both [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) and [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker). Follow the installation steps from their documentation guide.
2. Then implement 2 small functions to do image pick and upload to firebase. Here is the sample code.

```
// 1. Import required library
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

// 2. Create a function to pick the image
const pickImage = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(pickerOptions, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) return;

      if (response.error) {
        const message = `An error was occurred: ${response.error}`;
        reject(new Error(message));
        return;
      }

      const { path: uri } = response;
      resolve(uri);
    });
  });
};

// 3. Create a function to upload to firebase
const uploadImage = async (fileName, uri) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`uploads/${filename}`)
        .putFile(uri)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    }
  );
}
```

3. Then simply firing both function as you need, here is the sample to pick and immediately upload it.

```
const pickImageAndUpload = async () => {
  const uri = await pickImage();
  const fileName = 'someImage.jpg';
  const { state, downloadURL } = await uploadImage(fileName, uri);
}
```

Comment: how to set my firebase config  by using react-native-firebase  ?

Comment: you can follow these installation steps https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios to set your firebase config

Answer (score 0):

```
async function uploadImageAsync(itemImage, passedParameter, ItemName, ItemDesc, ItemPrice, ItemWeight) {



     const response = await fetch(itemImage);
      const blob = await response.blob();
       console.log("uri of the elements ius", blob)

      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      var file = blob

     var metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      };
      const timeStamp = Date.now();
      var uploadTask = storageRef.child('CategoryDescription' + "/" + `${passedParameter}` + "/" + `${ItemName}`).put(file, metadata);
```

//For image pick

```
pickImage = async () => {
 const { CAMERA, CAMERA_ROLL } = Permissions;
 const permissions = {
  [CAMERA]: await Permissions.askAsync(CAMERA),
  [CAMERA_ROLL]: await Permissions.askAsync(CAMERA_ROLL),
 };

 if (permissions[CAMERA].status === 'granted' && permissions[CAMERA_ROLL].status === 'granted') {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
 allowsEditing: false,
 aspect:[4,3],
 quality: 0.5,
  });
  // console.log(result);

  if (!result.cancelled) {
 this.setState({ itemImage: result.uri });
  }
 }
```